# Pass Jquery variable to HTML so it can be picked up in multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm struggling to get this working but I may be going completely off track with this. I'm creating a jquery mobile webapp and I'm trying to use a variable that is declared when a popup is created, in a different on click function. The way that I thought to do this is:

click here to run function `LoadCancelReservationPopup` and pass some id's to the JQ

```
<a onclick= LoadCancelReservationPopup('" . $row ['sizecodeid'] ."','" . $row ['unitid'] ."') class='ui-btn ui-mini'>Cancel</a>
```

Run this function

```
function LoadCancelReservationPopup(sizecode,unit) {

var sizecode = (sizecode);
var unit = (unit);

$("#cancelReservationSizecode").html(sizecode);
$("#cancelReservationUnit").html(unit);

 $("#reservationCancelPopup").popup("open");
$("#reservationCancelPopup").trigger('create');

};
```

That function opens this popup and the ids that were passed are now being displayed in the divs

```
<div data-role='popup' id='reservationCancelPopup' data-theme='a' style='min-width: 300px;'>
    <div data-role='main' class='ui-content'>
        <div data-role='header' data-theme='a'>
            <h1>Cancel Reservation</h1>
        </div>
        <p>Are you sure you want to cancel this reservation?</p>
        <div id='cancelReservationUnit' name='cancelReservationUnit' class="unit"></div>
        <div id='cancelReservationSizecode' name='cancelReservationSizecode' class="sizecode"></div>

        <a href='#' class='ui-btn ui-btn-c' data-transition='pop' id='loadCancelCustomerReservation' name='loadCancelCustomerReservation'>Yes Cancel Reservation</a>
        <a href='#' class='ui-btn ui-btn-c' data-rel='back' data-transition='pop' id='CloseCancelCustomerReservationPopup'>No Return to Customer Details</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that when the `loadCancelCustomerReservation` function is called, the popups that I expected to contain the jquery variables are empty, these variables will eventually be passed to PHP via ajax but I can't figure out how I can use these variables in my 2 different functions. Is it not possible to pass jquery variables in this way?

```
$("#loadCancelCustomerReservation").click(function(){

  var sizecode = $('#cancelReservationSizecode').val();
  var unit = $('#cancelReservationUnit').val();

    window.alert(sizecode);
    window.alert(unit);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `.val()` on a `<div>` tag, when you're setting the value with `.html()`.

Change your code to this:

```
$("#loadCancelCustomerReservation").click(function(){

  var sizecode = $('#cancelReservationSizecode').html();
  var unit = $('#cancelReservationUnit').html();

    window.alert(sizecode);
    window.alert(unit);
});
```

Comment: +1 & accepted! Thanks so much - I've been looking at this for ages and the answer was so simple :O